# How can I cause a specific animation to trigger from a specific event, like having all menu tabs closed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

So basically, I'm trying to create a splash page with 4 columns that show and hide horizontally, using ".animate". At the moment, I have succeeded in creating the basic layout, however the container that the 4 columns are in (which expand to the size of 5 when a column is opened) becomes offset from the center of the page when a column is opened. The container div is absolute positioned to be centered on the x and y axises. I attempted to make the whole div shift left back into the center, however when the column is closed, the div does not shift back. So my question is, how can I get the div to shift back when all columns are closed?

```
 // JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button1").click(function(){
      $(".row").not("#button1").animate();
    $("#slide1").animate({
      width:'toggle'
    });
    $("#slide2").animate({
        width:'hide'
    });
    $("#slide3").animate({
        width:'hide'
    });
    $("#slide4").animate({
        width:'hide'
    });
  });
  $("#button2").click(function(){
      $(".row").not("#button2").animate();
    $("#slide2").animate({
      width:"toggle"
    });
    $("#slide1").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
    $("#slide3").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
    $("#slide4").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
  });
  $("#button3").click(function(){
      $(".row").not("#button3").animate();
    $("#slide3").animate({
      width:"toggle"
    });
    $("#slide1").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
    $("#slide2").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
    $("#slide4").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
  });
  $("#button4").click(function(){
      $(".row").not("#button4").animate();
    $("#slide4").animate({
      width:"toggle"
    });
    $("#slide1").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
    $("#slide3").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
    $("#slide2").animate({
        width:"hide"
    });
  });
  // reposition container //
  $("#button1,#button2,#button3,#button4").click(function(){
      $("#container").animate({
          left:'50%',
          marginLeft:'-500px'
      });
  });
});
```

On a side note, I'm also just teaching myself jQuery, so I apologize for any vagueness. I am willing to try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but I set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/taK9K/) that I think matches what you're doing.  Basically, I'm really relying on CSS to handle the positioning more than anything.  jQuery is just used to expand and collapse the selected column and reset the container width. Instead of using `position:absolute` I'm using set widths and `margin:0 auto`.  That way I don't need to worry about calculating things like the left side offset position when the container is changing size.

Comment: Thank you for this, it is very similar to what I am trying to do, however I am also trying to have the columns centered vertically as well and margin 0 auto doesn't seem do that.

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsFiddle so I can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Yeah, here's all the code I have. http://jsfiddle.net/5s6gC/ You can see how I have the entire container shift left to re-center it, but when all columns are closed, it's off center. And also note, it is vertically centered, so margin 0 auto won't work.